# Which versions of choice fail to prove Banach-Tarski paradox?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In a prior [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044220/can-sf-ac-omega-and-sf-dc-be-generalized) about generalizing $\sf DC$ and $\sf AC_\omega$, the answer mentioned many versions of choice. Now of those versions, which ones fail to entail Banach-Tarski "B-T" paradox? I know that AC$_\omega$, and DC doesn't prove it, but what about the other versions? What is the strongest among those versions that fails to prove B-T paradox?

Comment: We don't know enough about the failure of B-T to answer that. We know it follows from Hahn–Banach, but that's not enough to tell us much more.