# How much choice is preserved in Gitik models of ZF?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, axioms

In a *[Gitik](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02760939)* model of $\sf ZF$ choice is obviousely lost since all uncountable cardinals are singular and of cofinality $\omega$. Now that choice is lost doesn't by itself entail that weaker forms of choice are not preserved.

> Up to which stage in the choice spectrums [$\sf DC_{< \kappa}, \sf 
> AC_X^Y(Z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044220/can-sf-ac-omega-and-sf-dc-be-generalized?answertab=active#tab-top) choice can be preserved in a Gitik Model of $\sf ZF$?

Comment: Why do you expect any choice survives at all?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, is there a provable result to the contrary? If there is none, then the possibility is there; and this can be useful.

Comment: @Zuhair: What do you mean? All limit ordinals have countable cofinality, so countable choice fails very badly. The real numbers are a countable union of countable sets, so again, countable choice fails real bad. Consequently, DC fails very bad.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But is anything preserved along the line of BPI, "every set can be linearly ordered" etc.?