# Does "ZF + no amorphous sets" implies some form of choice?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

If we forbid existence of [amorphous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set) sets, then does that prove axiom of choice? Or some form of choice?

Where by a "form of choice" I mean something along [those lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4044234/489784).

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Clearly it is consistent that there are no amorphous sets, but other Dedekind finite sets exist. So clearly not countable choice or anything that implies it...

Comment: so it doesn't enforce any known form of choice, I mean weak forms?

Comment: Again, what kind of "weak forms"? Sure, it implies that every infinite set can be split into two infinite sets. Great. But that's not really an interesting answer to your question, is it?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, this is not a known weak form of choice. I mean of the known ones. Apparently the answer is No.

Comment: Unless you define exactly what "weak form of choice" means, one standard interpretation is "somewhere between ZF and ZFC", in which case it is a weak form of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, well I meant a form of choice along the known lines that are either sequence based or cardinality based. I'll search in one of my old questions where you actually answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not at all.

The Cohen model, for example, does not have any amorphous sets. The second Cohen model does not have any either, although the proof is slightly more involved.

In either case, countable choice fails, and there are Dedekind-finite sets. In the latter case, countable choice from families of pairs fails as well.